# Try except on shape of an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have some trouble with an function and a try except statements.
What i want is similar with the following example script.
I want raise an error based on the shape of the input arrays. I have two options `shape = (4,)` or `shape = (1,)`.

```
def simple_func(a, b):
    try:
        return (a / b)
    except:
        print('Error Raised')
        a = other_function(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3])
        b = other_function(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3])
        return (a / b)
```

I know the same functionality the other way around the function is much more simple(below). That's True but i think that in 80% of the situations the shape of `a` and `b` have the `shape = (1,)` so i want it as fast as possible to calculate...

```
def simple_func2(a, b):
    try:
        a = other_function(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3])
        b = other_function(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3])
        return (a / b)
    except IndexError:
        print('Error Raised')
        return (a / b)
```

So exist there an method or exception so i can use the first function? This because i don't get it to raise an exception on what i want. At this moment i only see a way to use an If statement.

The `other_function` have 4 inputs and as result 1 output(return) for an easy example do something easy as:

```
def other_function(a,b,c,d):
    return(a + b + c + d)
```

Comment: What's the actual implementation of `other_function`?

Comment: The `other_function` is out of scope of my question. My problem is how to generatemy function so that is raises an exception. How can i check the `shape` so that it raise an exception or do i need an `If`, `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

With a function `other_function` as simple as your example, your code simplifies to

```
def simple_func2(a, b):
    return numpy.sum(a) / numpy.sum(b)
```

which works with all and any array shapes.